# @ManyToMany collections in JPA - foreign key constraint fails - (simulate likes and dislikes buttons)

Tags: java, jsf, jpa

I'm trying to render like/dislike buttons using JPA and JSF

```
@Entity
public class APost implements Serializable {
    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected Collection<User> likes;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected Collection<User> dislikes;

    @Transient
    public Integer getLikesNumber() {
        if (likes == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return likes.size();
    }

    public Collection<User> getLikes() {
        return likes;
    }

    public void setLikes(Collection<User> likes) {
        this.likes = likes;
    }

    public void addLikes(User user) {
        if (likes == null) {
            likes = new HashSet<>();
        }
        likes.add(user);
    }

    public void removeLikes(User user) {
        if (likes != null) {
            likes.remove(user);
        }
    }

    @Transient
    public Integer getDislikesNumber() {
        if (dislikes == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return dislikes.size();
    }

    public Collection<User> getDislikes() {
        return dislikes;
    }

    public void setDislikes(Collection<User> dislikes) {
        this.dislikes = dislikes;
    }

    public void addDislikes(User user) {
        if (dislikes == null) {
            dislikes = new HashSet<>();
        }
        dislikes.add(user);
    }

    public void removeDislikes(User user) {
        if (dislikes != null) {
            dislikes.remove(user);
        }
    }
}
```

The User Class :

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    ...

    @Id
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "likes")
    protected Collection<APost> likes;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "dislikes")
    protected Collection<APost> dislikes;

    public Collection<APost> getLikes() {
        return likes;
    }

    public void addLikes(APost post) {
        if (likes == null) {
            likes = new HashSet<>();
        }
        likes.add(post);
    }

    public void removeLikes(APost post) {
        if (likes != null) {
            likes.remove(post);
        }
    }

    public Collection<APost> getDislikes() {
        return dislikes;
    }

    public void addDislikes(APost post) {
        if (dislikes == null) {
            dislikes = new HashSet<>();
        }
        dislikes.add(post);
    }

    public void removeDislikes(APost post) {
        if (dislikes != null) {
            dislikes.remove(post);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        User uObj = (User) obj;
        return getEmail().equals(uObj.getEmail());
    }
}
```

Facelet : post.xhtml

```
...
<h:commandLink
    action="#{bean.addLike(post.id)}"
    <h:graphicImage library="images" name="thumb-up-24x31.png"></h:graphicImage>
</h:commandLink>
...
```

Bean.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ConversationScoped
public class OnePostManager implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB
    private IPostFacade postFacade;

    @EJB
    private IUserFacade userFacade;

    @Inject
    private LoginManager loginManager;

    ...

    public String addLike(Long postId) {
        if (loginManager.getConnected().equals(false)) {
            return "login?redirect=post&&faces-redirect=true";
        }

        if (postId != null) {
            APost post = postFacade.find(postId);
            User user = userFacade.find(loginManager.getEmail());
            post.addLikes(user);
            postFacade.edit(post);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, when I click on the "like" button, I got an exception :

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted
...
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-   3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`medianovens`.`APOST_USER`, CONSTRAINT `FK_APOST_USER_likes_EMAIL` FOREIGN KEY (`likes_EMAIL`) REFERENCES `USER` (`EMAIL`))
Error Code: 1452
Call: INSERT INTO APOST_USER (dislikes_EMAIL, dislikes_ID) VALUES (?, ?)
bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="dislikes" sql="INSERT INTO APOST_USER (dislikes_EMAIL, dislikes_ID) VALUES (?, ?)")
...
```

When I look at my database, I've got one table called APOST_USER with 4 columns : dislikes_EMAIL, dislikes_ID, likes_EMAIL, likes_ID

So I suppose that when it tries to add an entry that defines which post a user likes, it tries to fill likes_EMAIL and likes_ID but also expects some values for dislikes_EMAIL and dislikes_ID ...

How can I solve this ?

Note : 
When I remove all code concerning dislike functions, the code works OK (My table APOST_USER only has 2 columns, likes_EMAIL and likes_ID) and an entry can be added, but everything goes wrong if I add all code regarding dislike function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your JPA provider is trying to be smart and combine the two references to APost into one.  What you should probably do is look into the [@JoinTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html) annotation, which would allow you to definitively specify different tables should be used for your Like and Dislike features.
http://blog.jbaysolutions.com/2012/12/17/jpa-2-relationships-many-to-many/ shows how this is used in practice.

Here's what I think it should look like to fix your mapping problem:

```
@Entity
public class APost implements Serializable {
    ...

    @JoinTable(name="post_likes")
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected Collection<User> likes;

    @JoinTable(name="post_dislikes")
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected Collection<User> dislikes;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign both sides of the relationship:

```
    post.addLikes(user);
    user.addLikes(post);
```